# Adding a Scrollbar to a Tkinter Graph of data which goes off the bottom for the screen

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Brand New to tkinter so please bare with. I've taken data from elsewhere and now I want to display in a table format with multiple data colums for that row. When I display the data like this it goes off the bottom for the screen and I lose data. How do I add a scrollbar to access the rest of this data?

```py
from tkinter import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
import requests
import re

root = Tk()


def TableCreate(Title,Cost, count,col):
    ##Title and Cost are both Lists.

    #vertscroll = Scrollbar()
    #vertscroll.config(command=grid.yview)

    ##This was called Iterativley so would print over and over again
    btn_column = Button(root, text = "Link")
    btn_column.grid(row = count, column=col)
    btn_column = Button(root, text=Title)
    btn_column.grid(row = count,column=col+1)
    btn_column = Button(root, text=Cost)
    btn_column.grid(row = count,column=col+2)
```